# xctool fails to clean my iOS project

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xctool

I'm using `xctool` (v0.1.16) for an iOS project, which is configured as follows:

- a workspace
- two targets `Project` and `ProjectTests`
- two schemes `Project` and `ProjectTests`

I have a `.xctool-args` file with the workspace and `Project` scheme configured.

I run `xctool build` and `xctool -scheme ProjectTests -sdk iphonesimulator test` successfully.

However, I run `xctool clean` and the following happens:

- 1st it runs `xcodebuild clean Project` successfully
- 2nd it runs `xcodebuild build clean` which fails with the error:

  - Scheme Tests is not currently configured for the clean action.

It is strange because I don't have a `Tests` scheme at all.

I run `xctool clean -showTasks` and have more details about the error. It runs and fails at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild \
  -configuration Debug \
  -workspace    /var/folders/b7/472b_skj24gf7wmw6c3krp5c0000gn/T/xctool_temp_KMbH0e/Tests.xcworkspace \
  -scheme    Tests \
OBJROOT=/Users/paristote/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fmyqwebczmtplydrfhcmrdzezcft/Build/Intermediates \
SYMROOT=/Users/paristote/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fmyqwebczmtplydrfhcmrdzezcft/Build/Products \
SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/paristote/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-fmyqwebczmtplydrfhcmrdzezcft/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders \
  -IDECustomDerivedDataLocation=/var/folders/b7/472b_skj24gf7wmw6c3krp5c0000gn/T/xctool_temp_KMbH0e/DerivedData \
  clean
```

However, the same command executed separately finishes successfully.

The workspace at `/var/folders/b7/472b_skj24gf7wmw6c3krp5c0000gn/T/xctool_temp_KMbH0e/Tests.xcworkspace` simply references two projects, the `Project` xcodeproj and `Pods` xcodeproj. It does contain a Tests scheme with a build action.

Why does this command fail in the 1st place? Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Edit: temp workspace and scheme now exist

Comment: It may be related to https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/311.

Comment: How did you resolve it at the end?

Comment: I didn't, I skip xctool entirely and use `xcodebuild clean` instead

Comment: I now works with xctool v0.2+ (tested on 0.2.2, 0.2.3 and 0.2.5).

Comment: I'm getting the same error: 
xcodebuild: error: Scheme Transient Testing is not currently configured for the clean action.
I'm using fastlane version 2.81.0 to automate tests on the Jenkins CI using scan and then slather for reporting coverage.
xcodebuild from Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

"Transient Testing" scheme does not exist anywhere I can see in my project / workspace. 
I've deleted derived data and re-built / tested with no luck.

Build, testing and coverage works fine from xCode itself.

I've tried everything I've found online so far and no luck...

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by checking the "shared" box for the main scheme:

> 1. Choose Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes.
> 2. Select the Shared option for the scheme to share, and click OK.
>
> source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeShare.html

Comment: Which scheme are you talking about? The `Project`, `ProjectTests` or the temporary `Tests` ?

Comment: Anyway, I haven't tested yet but I'm pretty sure it was fixed in xctool v0.2.5 cf https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/311

Comment: I now works with xctool v0.2+ (tested on 0.2.2, 0.2.3 and 0.2.5).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by

- Unchecking auto create schemes in XCode scheme management
- Removing and recreating the scheme(s) I wanted to build (in your case Project and ProjectTests)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure it was fixed in xctool v0.2.5 cf https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/311 but I haven't tested yet.

Comment: Unfortunately not, that was the version I used also.

Comment: OK thanks that's an interesting feedback, I'll check on my side and update this issue asap.

Comment: I now works with xctool v0.2+ (tested on 0.2.2, 0.2.3 and 0.2.5). I'm sure that auto create schemes was unchecked before and I'm pretty sure I didn't recreate all my schemes, so I don't really know how it got fixed though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in xCode 7. I fixed this issue by doing the following:
- Choose Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes.
- Select the "Shared" option for the scheme, and click OK